# how to check if the phone number already registered firebase swift

Tags: swift, firebase

I want a method or if statement if the user already registered before user segue go to main ViewController else Go To Fill Form ViewController that the user can fill all let's say personal Info to upload to Firebase database and it's not just for one user.

My code is:

```
@IBAction func login(_ sender: Any) {

    let credintal :PhoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: defaults.string(forKey: "authVID")!, verificationCode: entercode.text!)


    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credintal) { (user,error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        }else {
            // i need if statment here 
            // example if no user registred   {Go go 
            let userInfo = user?.providerData[0]

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "fillform", sender: 
            Any?.self)} 
          else { Go To elf.performSegue(withIdentifier: "MainView", 
               sender: Any?.self)} 
             }


            print("Provide ID \(userInfo?.providerID)")
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "fillform", sender: Any?.self)


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How should we know if your user is registered or not? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it in else you have to check for the error code that the sign in returned so that you know if user is not registered or there is some other error. So, in your code:

```
if error != nil {
    //Handle the logic here if user not signed in 
}
```

You can check against the list of error code that are returned. In your case you can check for `FIRAuthErrorCodeUserNotFound` which is a common error code to all API methods.